# C# Retrieving data from ListView with GridView

Tags: c#, xaml, listview

I have found some articles to get data to be put into a listview with a databinding on gridviewcolums but I am needing to retrieve this data when a line is selected from the list, this is the code i have to fill the list and "attempt" to retrieve the data.
As far as i have found, please have very different ways of putting this data into a listview and I assume my problem is that I do not know the correct way to retrieve it with it formatted in the XAML this way.

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{ // This is When a button is clicked to populate the List
    Operate op = new Operate();
    List<object> users = op.GetUser();
    if (users != null)
    {
        ResultsView.Items.Clear();
        foreach (UserPrincipal user in users)
        {
            ResultsView.Items.Add(new {Col1 = user.GivenName, Col2 = user.Surname, Col3 = user.SamAccountName});
        }
    }
}
private void ListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{ // This is When a line is selected and should get the info from the line
    if (ResultsView.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        string sel = ResultsView.SelectedItem.Col1;
    }
}
```

And this is the XAML for the list

```
<ListView
    x:Name="ResultsView"
    Margin="5,5,5,5"
    SelectionMode="Single"
    SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="H1" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Col1}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="H2" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Col2}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="H3" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Col3}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Very sorry about any weird formatting or errors, just starting with this a few days ago.
Here is a picture of the list when it is populated, looks as I expect it to.

Comment: What is the issue you're having right now? Error? Also, `//` is used to make a comment, not `\\\` :)

Comment: Ty for the //. The error is that the object ResultsView.SelectedItem.Col1 is saying that the object does not contain a defenition for Col1.

Comment: Error 1 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Col1' and no extension method 'Col1' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @rhamilton - Check this msdn article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.selecteditem.aspx , specifically the example given. It should point you to casting your selected item as a type so that you may access the properties.

Comment: My problem is that, My 'if' statement (if ResultsView.SelectedItem != null) is passing true. and if I add ResultsView.SelectedItem to my watch list, i get { Col1 = "Connie", Col2 = "Jones", Col3 = "CJones" } Which is the exact syntax of how I added it to the list. I just dont know how to separate it back out. It seems to me that I should be able to do ResultsView.SelectedItem.Col1 to retrieve this, but ResultsView.SelectedItem is the Type "<Anonymous Type>" I am yet unable to figure out how to extract from an Anonymous Type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer was in Travis J's comment somewhat. I knew that I may have needed to create this table in a different way so that the output of SelectedItem does not come up as anonymous type. So I have redone how the table is constructed and am now using DataTable.

```
private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Operate op = new Operate();
    DataTable users = op.GetUser();
    if (users != null)
    {
        ResultsView.ItemsSource = users.DefaultView;
    }
}
private void ListView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{

    if (ResultsView.SelectedItem != null)
    {
        DataRowView line = ResultsView.SelectedItem as DataRowView;
        string stuff = line.Row.ItemArray[2].ToString();

        MessageBox.Show(stuff);
    }
}
```

And this made a need for the XAML to change so that the binding is looking for a path from the datatable.

```
<ListView
    x:Name="ResultsView"
    Margin="5,5,5,5"
    SelectionMode="Single"
    SelectionChanged="ListView_SelectionChanged">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="H1" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=FirstName}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="H2" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=LastName}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Width="100" Header="H3" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=UserName}"/>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I have decided not to include my own method for creating the datatable but I will provide the link that showed me the quickest way.

http://www.dotnetperls.com/datatable